# Magento code error

Tags: php, magento

when we add to cart then site is not working and when we back to page then it shows 1 item to cart with blank page and  when we flush cache of browser then site is working properly. 
when we check error in *error_log* page the it shows

**PHP Fatal error**:

```
Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object in
/var/www/html/thetyrecottage/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Collection.php
on line 2013
```

and the code is

```
$backend = $attribute->getBackend();
```

Comment: had you modify any core file?

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is some module or customization that is causing this issue.

If you have some module that add product to cart, disable it and check.
Try to use default Magento theme and check if problem occurs.

If any of these solve, disable all custom modules and if the problem gone, try to enable each module at time to check which is causing this problem.

Do not disable module in System -> Configuration -> Advanced. These only disable the output (html) of module but it still working. Disable the module editing app/etc/modules file or rename the file to something like .DISABLED (any ext different of .xml)

Regards